# MFC application Crashes in NTDLL.dll

Tags: windows, mfc, crash, ntdll

I have an MFC based application. It keeps looking for a file after few seconds (using CreateTimerQueueTimer based timer) and perform some action. This is always crashing (for unknown reason) on XP. This application works fine on windows 7 and windows 8. But problem on XP is persistent.

Below is the call stack which doesn't show any help 
[image: Call stack after the crash]

Disassembly screenshot is below:

[image]

**EDIT1:**

I changed few settings and I got this new call stack. But still did not get the clue.:
[image]

I am not understanding how can i track down the reason for crash. Is there any hint or any way to track it sown from disassembly? Or may there be any issue with system's NTDLL.DLL file? Any help is welcome.

Comment: That stack trace is missing the important parts. You need to persuade Visual Studio to load the debug symbols for your executable.

Comment: That is the problem. I mean only for this issue, it is giving the call stack as shown above. That is why I am not able to catch the culprit. Do you have any idea how can i ask visual studio debugger to give me that?

Comment: Is the application built with debug symbols?  If so, you should be able to specify the location of the symbols within the project properties.

Comment: Well, I can see that my debug information Format is set to /ZI . Do i need to do anything else?

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio on the XP machine? Or are you remote debugging it? Or are you debugging a dump file? Getting the symbols loaded might depend on the answer to those questions. In the meantime, try putting the .PDB files next to the .EXE file.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 in XP to debug the problem. It is not remote debugging. I have two other files with my executable in debug folder - MyApp.pdb and My App.ink

Comment: I have edited the question and posted a new call stack. Still clueless about the error. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing the stack, I realized that there might be a problem with the timer call back. I chnaged my timer (createtimerqueuetimer function) to a wait thread and problem was solved. But still the question is open for answer to ***why timer callback was crashing after few calls***? I am just setting and resetting the variable in callback function after 30 sec. so I am not suspecting any pointer related issue.

**EDIT1:**

Finaly I Got the answer. I needed to change

`void MyTimerCallbackRoutine(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)`

To:

```
VOID CALLBACK MyTimerCallbackRoutine(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
```

The problem was related to timer callback function. generally the CALLBACK and WINAPIs are defined as stdcall where as normal functions by default uses cdecl.